# How to re-index Elasticsearch without stale reads?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have indices with heavy read/write operations.
My indices have a read and a write alias.
When I need to update the mapping in my indices I go about this process:

1. create a new index with the new mapping,
2. add write-alias to the new index.
3. delete the write-alias to the old index.
4. reindex the data like this

   ```
   POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
   {
   "conflicts": "proceed",

   "source": {
   "index": "old-index"
   },
    "dest": {
      "op_type": "create", 
      "index": "new-index"
    }
   }
   ```
5. While reindexing read-alias points to old index while the write-alias points to the new index
6. When the re-indexing is complete, I create a read-alias on the new index and delete the read-alias on the old index.

This process works fine, but there is one caveat. While re-indexing the data is stale to the applications reading, i.e. updates can not be read until I have switched read to the new index.

Since I have quite large indices, the re-indexing takes many hours.

Is there any way to handle re-indexing without reading stale data?

I would of course like to write to two indices at the same time while re-indexing, but as I understand it's not possible.

The only workaround I can think of is to edit on the client-side, so all writes go to both indexes in two separate requests during re-indexing.

Any ideas or comments are much appreciated

Comment: Another issue with what you're doing is that you are at risk of overwriting recent data written to the new index with old data reindexed from the old index. Say, for instance, document 1 is in the old index and now gets written to the new index (after step 2). When you start reindexing (step 4), is it possible that the "old" version of document 1 present in old-index overwrites the newer version of document 1 that's already been written in new-index?

Comment: Thanks for your input, I hope I understand the docs correct. It says: "Setting op_type to create causes _reindex to only create missing documents in the destination. All existing documents will cause a version conflict".Since the documents have the same id in old and new index and proceed on conflict only keeps the reindexing from throwing error, not overwriting existing documents, right?

Comment: My bad, sorry, I overlooked that line. Can you explain how you read your data? What's your typical query?

Comment: There is no typical query, reads are comming from a Search API that does, multimatch, nested, fuzzy, keyword, prefix searches to name a few.